# custom fetch from table can't execute in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my php codem , it must be work , but error in execute ! 
what the problem ?!
i am a new PDO programmer

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
        $_SESSION['msg_login']='<script type="text/javascript">alert("error");    </script>';   
        header("location:index.php");
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_login` WHERE `user` = :user AND `pass` = :pass ;";
        $result = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $pass = hash_pass($_POST['password']);
        $query = $result->execute(array(
        "user"=>$_POST['email'],"pass"=>$pass));
        $num1 = $result->fetchColumn();
        if ($num1==1){
            $fetch = $connect->query($sql);
            $fetch->execute(array("user"=>$_POST['email'],"pass"=>$pass));
            while ($rows=$fetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo 'ok';  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error : Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT 
            *  
        FROM 
            `user_login` 
        WHERE 
            `user` = :user AND 
            `pass` = :pass";

$inputs = array(
    ":user" => $_POST['email'],
    ":pass" => hash_pass($_POST['password'])
);

$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($inputs);

$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($user);
} else {
    echo "bad login";
}
```